# Does Standard Azure CDN support CORS

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

Is CORS supported in Standard edition of Azure CDN or is it only available in premium tier. I am looking for "wildcard or single origin scenario"

This is what they mention in the below link

> CORS on Azure CDN will work automatically with no additional
>   configuration when the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is set to
>   wildcard (*) or a single origin.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-cors#wildcard-or-single-origin-scenarios

Comment: Based on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-cors#azure-cdn-standard-profiles yes. Looks like they cache your back-end CORS response.

Answer (score 1):

@juunas, As the comment, the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-cors#azure-cdn-standard-profiles) states that, **standard Azure CDN** allows for multiple origins is to use [query string caching.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-query-string)

> Enable the query string setting for the CDN endpoint and then use a
>   unique query string for requests from each allowed domain. Doing so
>   will result in the CDN caching a separate object for each unique query
>   string. This approach is not ideal, however, as it will result in
>   multiple copies of the same file cached on the CDN.

So, the best way is to use **Azure CDN Premium from Verizon**, which exposes some advanced functionality. If so, you will need to create a rule to check the **Origin** header on the request. If it's a valid origin, the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header with the origin provided will be set in the request. If it's not, this header will be omitted by the rule and the browser also will reject the request.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin on your origin server. **Standard Azure CDN will respect your CORS header**. Its working just fine for me. I am glad I tried setting the header on the origin server instead of upgrading to the Premium CDN.

Comment: this doesn't actually work; that's not even how CORS works. you must have something else configured.